# Как сделать кнопку удаления?

Tags: php

Как сделать кнопку удаления строки таблицы? Короче, на странице онлайн-записи есть таблица, в эту таблицу записываются клиенты, но после всего, админ авторизируется на сайте и выбирает каких клиентов ему нужно удалить. Потом нажимает на кнопку, и клиенты, которые на странице, удаляются из таблицы и из базы данных. Вот такая волшебная кнопка нужна...

Comment: @kiberchainik, "Знающие люди" любят свой язык. Старайтесь использовать все правила при оформлении вопроса.

Answer (score 5):

Примерный вариант. Позволяет удалять сразу нескольких пользователей.

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['del_users']) && sizeof($_POST['del_users'])){
    $result = mysql_query('delete from users where id in (' . implode(',', array_keys($_POST['del_users'])) . ')');
}
?>

<form action="" method="post">
    User 1: <input type="checkbox" name="del_users[1]" />
    User 2: <input type="checkbox" name="del_users[2]" />
    User 15: <input type="checkbox" name="del_users[15]" />
    <input type="submit" value="Delete!" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if(isset($_POST['del_user'])) {
    $result = mysql_query("DELETE FROM users where user_id = ".$_POST['del_user']."");
}
```

**сама кнопка**

```
<form action="" methot="POST">
<input type="hidden" name="del_user" value="{id пользователя}" />
<input type="submit" value="удалить" />
</form>
```

Comment: Удаляет, спасибо за помощь, но она удаляет всю базу, а мне нужно чтоб можно было выбрать например с помощью чекбокса то, что нужно удалить и затем удалять...

Comment: Вы имели введу все поля? Наверное вы допустили ошибку при редактировании кода под себя. 

Покажите ваш код, который генерирует юзеров

Comment: У вас есть ася или где можно с Вами связаться?

Comment: Присмотритесь коду ling'a, это то что вам нужно.